# Permissional denial in live wallpaper settings

Tags: android

I have configured settings activity as follows:
**xml/wallpaper.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wallpaper android:description="@string/appName" android:thumbnail="@drawable/icon"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:settingsActivity="com.xyz.abc.LiveWallpaperSettings"/>
```

**manifest file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xyz.abc"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-feature android:name="android.software.live_wallpaper" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/appName" >
        <service
            android:name="CustomWallpaper"
            android:label="@string/appName"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
                android:resource="@xml/wallpaper" />
        </service>

        <activity android:name="com.xyz.abc.LiveWallpaperSettings" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.PREFERENCE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**LiveWallpaperSettings java code:**

```
public class LiveWallpaperSettings extends PreferenceActivity
implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings);
}


@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
        String key) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

The error I see when click the settings button on my device is:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(13164): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
E/AndroidRuntime(13164):        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3607)
E/AndroidRuntime(13164):        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4212)
E/AndroidRuntime(13164):        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17476)
E/AndroidRuntime(13164):        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
E/AndroidRuntime(13164):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
E/AndroidRuntime(13164):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
E/AndroidRuntime(13164):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
E/AndroidRuntime(13164):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(13164):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
E/AndroidRuntime(13164):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
E/AndroidRuntime(13164):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
E/AndroidRuntime(13164):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(13164): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
E/AndroidRuntime(13164):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(13164):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
E/AndroidRuntime(13164):        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3602)
E/AndroidRuntime(13164):        ... 11 more
E/AndroidRuntime(13164): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { cmp=com.xyz.abc/.LiveWallpaperSettings (has e
xtras) } from ProcessRecord{4236f958 13164:com.android.wallpaper.livepicker/u0a10036} (pid=13164, uid=10036) not exported from uid 10073
E/AndroidRuntime(13164):        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
E/AndroidRuntime(13164):        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
E/AndroidRuntime(13164):        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1939)
E/AndroidRuntime(13164):        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1418)
E/AndroidRuntime(13164):        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3388)
E/AndroidRuntime(13164):        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3349)
E/AndroidRuntime(13164):        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3584)
E/AndroidRuntime(13164):        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3552)
E/AndroidRuntime(13164):        at com.android.wallpaper.livepicker.LiveWallpaperPreview.configureLiveWallpaper(LiveWallpaperPreview.java:125)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are trying to set Wallpaper if so you have to include following permission in android manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
```

I hope it solves your problem.